# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap'

Tags: typescript

I have this code to create smooth scrolling when a link is clicked on:

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item a') as NodeListOf<HTMLAnchorElement>;

navLinks.forEach((link: HTMLAnchorElement) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const target = document.querySelector(link.getAttribute('href'));

    if (target) {
      target.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Typescript is throwing an error (see question text) on the line where I set `target`, specifically on `document.querySelector(link.getAttribute('href'));`

If I replace that line with simple interpolation `` document.querySelector(`${link.getAttribute('href')}`); `` then the error goes away. Either way, my code works as intended, but its starting to give me involuntary twitching that I can't figure out the TS error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not every `<a>` has a `href`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href'));
```

```html
<a></a>
```

By doing

```
.querySelector(`${link.getAttribute('href')}`)
```

you're turning whatever `getAttribute` results in into a string - even if it's `null` (which may well result in `target` not existing).

To fix the TypeScript errors, consider adding `[href]` to your selector string to ensure that you only select elements with `href`s, then use `!` to assert to TypeScript that the `link` definitely has one.

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLAnchorElement>('.nav-item a[href]');

navLinks.forEach((link: HTMLAnchorElement) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const target = document.querySelector(link.getAttribute('href')!);

    if (target) {
      target.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  });
});
```

To make the code clearer, you also might consider replacing

```
const target = document.querySelector(link.getAttribute('href')!);
```

with a check of if the attribute begins with a `#` first (because *usually* an `href` won't be a valid selector string - the check will make it clearer that the code is meant to target IDs on the same page).

Comment: [The error itself is because the DOM types do not have a case for `querySelector` with `null` or `undefined`.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L10319-L10325) The function itself, works, but I assume that it was implemented this way because querying undefined is probably a bug.